# Is It possible to plot a water fall chart as shown in the below image?

Tags: highcharts

I need to plot a waterfall chart like below. In the chart, each column is a type of category and the value is calculated by adding the sub-types. How do we display the sub-types(ex: Gas 1, Gas 2) in the bottom and category(like Category 3) in the top. Is this possible in highcharts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `xAxis` with categories. For example:

```
xAxis: [{
  opposite: true,
  lineWidth: 0,
  categories: ['Start', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 'Category4', 'Balance']
}, {
  linkedTo: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  categories: ['', 'Sub-Category 1', 'Liquid 1<br>Liquid 2', 'Gas 1<br>Gas 2', 'Solid 1', ''],
  labels: {
    rotation: 0,
    y: -10
  }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a9bzeqw4/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels

Comment: Thankyou. This is what I was looking for.!

Comment: How do I give a different color for the bar in the negative region and another color for the same bar in the positive region for *isSum* bar ?

Comment: You can use `upColor`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.waterfall.upColor and `negativeColor`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.waterfall.negativeColor properties.